# Best practice in converting from 0.X: variable trees

Tags: openmdao

Is there a recommended best practice in converting variable trees from 0.X to 1.X? My intuition is to make variable trees into components, but I'm curious what the OpenMDAO team thinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we moved away from variable trees. Instead we just name the variables hierarchically like "top:sub:subsub:x, top:sub:subsub:y"

Comment: Thanks, Justin. What about the case where there was an instance in the variable tree? My intuition is to make it an object of the Component which previously contained the variable tree..

Comment: We don't suggest you pass objects as variables any more. This isn't differentiable and makes optimization really hard. So yes, make it an object of the group and pass the data you would need instead.

Answer (score 1):

Kilojoules,

I too was really upset with the elimination of variable trees; but, I was much more upset with how they failed to integrate with openmdao components and failed silently.  Good riddance.

I have been experimenting with numpy.ndarray as a replacement for variable trees.  See the Sellar example for details.  Creating multi-dimensional ndarray with field names seems to work well for a name-referenced data structure.  To create multidimensionality seems to require nesting of declarations which is similar to variable tree branches.

Note that the numpy.array (sic) is not compatible with openmdao, but numpy.ndarray (sic) works well since ndarray is a "structured" array object with size, shape, data type, etc specified in an internal dictionary.  Better than variable trees, the multi-dimensional ndarray provides multiple "views" of the same relationships with one (massive) global declaration which can be instantiated as a param within a component.  Populating the ndarray instance is made by field name-referenced assignment instead of some iteration.  It is more complicated to declare as ALL the information about the structured array must be provided to work within openmdao.  Also, numpy.ndarray is for rigidly fixed array sizes and relationships, just like variable trees.

I am not advocating this concept for every application, but do take a look for your situation.
Silvia